# Why there is a bubbling for parent's siblings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-bubbling

I create a simple slideToggle effect on click event but the '.close' event is generating bubbles. Both unbind() and stopImmediatePropagation() worked, but I don't understand why e.stopPropagation() won't work. 
Another question is why would 'close' click event triggered twice? 
Click on contact button few times, then click 'close' and you will see. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uz9h5tLw/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="close">X</div>
    <h3>Contact me</h3>
</div>
<button class="contact">Contact me</button>

var form = {
    container: $('.container'),

    init: function() {
        $(".contact.button").on('click', this.show);
    },
    show: function(){
            form.container.slideToggle(150);
            form.close();
    },
    close: function() {
        $('.close').on('click', function(e){
            form.container.slideToggle(150);
            // stopImmediatePropagation() and unbind() works; 
            // but why e.stopPropagation() does not work here?
        });
    }
};

form.init();

I could be wrong saying the click event is making bubble, because both elements don't have immediate relationship. I just don't know what is wrong here.
```

Answer (score 2):

You are subscribing to the same events again and again. Subscribing to an event does not override an existing subscription.

- Every time you press the `Contact Me` button, the function `show` is called.
- Every time the function `show` is called, the function `close` is called.
- Every time the function `close` is called, you add yet another listener to the 'X' button.

The result being, if you've pressed `Contact Me` twice, there would be two anonymous functions listening to the `X` button.

There are two alternative approaches here:

- Have a function called `toggleState`. It would have to remember what state it currently is, and open or close accordingly when the function is called. Then you must only subscribe to each event once.
- Have named functions rather then anonymous functions, and unsubscribe from events using `jQuery.off` at appropriate times.

Comment: Beginner here. I don't understand where the 3 close are called. Only form.close() called it in show method. How do I understand this?

Comment: @user2734550 - The `show` method is called multiple times. I've updated my answer to try and be more clear